# How to creating a vanilla forum plugin to do IOS push notifications

Tags: php, ios, plugins, apple-push-notifications, vanilla-forums

Hi I would like to have the ability to load additional external php classs files called easyapns in a new plugin I am writting, 
see http://www.easyapns.com/php-source

This would then allow me to send push messages to ios devices using event handlers.

Maybe just not understanding garden framework, but 
what is the best way to go about loading the class files from with a plugin, and how would I then reference the functions in the easyapns class??

Thanks for you help.. hopeful I can create a usefull plugin for all to use with a little help.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, [Managing Notification on iPad](http://www.recovery-ipad.com/set-up-configure-notifications-ipad.html) is not complicated.
The easiest way is clicking the "Settings -> Notifications" button. If you want to get notifications at the fastest speed, you can add widgets to Notification Center. That's it, after the above settings, you will be notified immediately. There's no need to worry about missing the WhatsApp messages, Mail, Voicemail, and more. Please feel free to contact us if you have any question on configuring notification center. So this way can create a vanilla forum plugin to do iOS push notifications.